# cling Jupyter TypeError: readlink: can't specify None for path argument

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cling

I guess I need some support on fighting with the following issue:

```
[I 01:32:06.539 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 81762983-2e89-47dc-a6f6-5f36d4f25865 restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter-cling-kernel", line 6, in <module>
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
File "/Users/Alexey/cling/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/scripts/jupyter-cling-kernel", line 4, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/Alexey/cling/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/clingkernel.py", line 317, in main
ClingKernelApp.launch_instance()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 595, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-122>", line 2, in initialize
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 421, in initialize
self.init_kernel()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 360, in init_kernel
user_ns=self.user_ns,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 405, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Alexey/cling/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/clingkernel.py", line 80, in __init__
whichCling = os.readlink(shutil.which('cling'))
TypeError: readlink: can't specify None for path argument
```

[W 01:32:09.546 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed`

In .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Developer/cling/bin:$PATH"
```

Checked everywhere - nothing similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile. Or if you're using any virtual environment start the notebook in your root environment